# How phone call in phone app is implemented in Android

Tags: android, phone-call

The question is related to my app behavior, which like phone app need to awaken from service done in background to active state in response to externally accepted (through Bluetooth) call. What happens, when phone call is received and call answer invitation is displayed?
a) Is this call answer invitation a pop-up notification by picking up which we enter phone app? Or,
b) Is this call answer invitation an activity, which is part of phone app?

What's a correct way to do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Rephrased. Please, review again.

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of the broadcast receiver which is made to listen the phone state(via intent filter) and when the phone state changes the onrecieve() of the broadcast receiver is executed which can contain a notification directly or an activity or any UI for that fact